# Achartengine: scolling and re-draw Pan. How can I do?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'm using achartengine and I show a ghraph where on the x axis are putted the last 30 days starting by the current date and on the y axis some values from 15 to 0. In my code I used

```
      for(int i=0; i<= array of value to be inserted i++){
         .....
         aRenderer.addXTextLabel(//value I want is showd on x axis);
         .....
      }
      aRenderer.setXAxisMin(dateMin);
      aRenderer.setXAxisMax(adateMax);
      aRenderer.setXLabels(0);
```

Now given that I customized my x labels, when I scroll on the right and on the left, the other labesl don't appeare. So I thought of create a new class that implements PanLinstener and in the panApplied() redraw the labels when I scroll the panel.
Someone has a better idea to to this?

This is what I obtain when I scroll to left from right:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I opted for implementing a PanLinstener, re-drawing the graphs in the panApplied() method.

Answer (score 0):

Under the panApplied() method you will have to rebuild the custom labels.
You will probably need to know the X axis range: renderer.getXAxixMin() and renderer.getXAxisMax() and add new custom labels between this interval.